# Unable to pass DesiredCapabilities from arquillian.xml with selenium grid

Tags: selenium-grid, jboss-arquillian, arquillian-drone

Unable to pass DesiredCapabilities from arquillian.xml with selenium grid

```
<property name="remoteAddress">${gridhubaddress}</property>
    <property name="remote">true</property>
    <property name="chromePrintOptions">true</property>
    <property name="chromeArguments">-start-maximized</property>    
        <property name="chromeExperimentalOption">  
    {
  "prefs": {
    "download.default_directory": "${downloadlocation}"
    }
    }
</property>
```

- Desired Capabilities were captured and worked as expected when executed without selenium grid
- Debugging with Remote WebDriver showed that it has the expected DesiredCapabilities (check screen attached) but when the browser was launched, it was launched without capabilites
- Initially my thought was `<property name="chromeExperimentalOption">` had an issue but when i added`<property name="chromeArguments">-start-maximized</property>`, it did not worked as well. Without Grid both worked.

DEBUG_REMOTE_WEBDRIVER
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update to the latest version of Drone: 2.4.2 - it should be fixed there.

Comment: Thanks Matouš Jobánek